# Getting the data from fetch for JSON

Tags: javascript, chart.js, fetch

I have a JSON as follows:

```
{
  "item":{
  "Labels": [ "Jan", "March", "July" ],
  "Data": [ 1, 20, 30 ]
}
}
```

I need to pass Data values into ChartJS using fetch JS.

I have the following code for that.

```
fetch(path).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.item.Data);
    // Chart Goes here

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: data.Labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: data.item.Data,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

});
```

but this does not work for ChartJS->  data.item.Data

Comment: Looks like you forgot something in `labels: data.Labels` :) Should be `labels: data.item.Labels` as well